# Use whereis can not find the file in the Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

In the Mac I installed the mysqlclient, use `whereis` can not find the `mysql_config`, but use `which` I can find, why use the `whereis` can not find it?

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:bin ldl$ whereis mysql_config
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:bin ldl$ which mysql_config
/usr/local/mysql/bin//mysql_config
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`whereis` uses a hardcoded list of paths to search. `which` uses your PATH.

/usr/local/mysql/bin isn't a standard location for binaries, so `whereis` doesn't search there. Presumably you've added that folder to your path (or the installer did), which means when `which` searches through your path folders, it finds it.

You can print the list of paths `whereis` searches by running the following:

```
$ sysctl user.cs_path
user.cs_path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Whereas your $PATH will generally have many more components. You can print your PATH with:

```
$ echo $PATH
```